# Mvc antiforgery token and akamai caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, antiforgerytoken, akamai

We have a form in a mvc web app that uses antiforgery token. The form uses ajax post request. The problem im having is the akamai caches the page for 5 mins and serves the cached page with cached antiforgery token to anothet client as a result that user gets a 500 server error upon submission be ause the antiforgerytoken does mpt exist from cache. Why would akamai cache get mixed up with antiforgery tokens between clients? Cache should be unique for each client. How is it possible that every client is seeimg thr same cached page from akamai?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually how the Akamai system works.  The cache servers provide the same pages for multiple users.  The right way to avoid this is to use property manager (or config manager if you haven't upgraded) to set a rule not to cache those specific pages.  It seems odd to send the token information in the page rather than in the headers or cookies, but if you are doing that you need to tell Akamai to except caching in that case.

Comment: Mvc antigorgery token sets a hidden field with request token and also sets a cookie with the token.also we cant disable caching for a page.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't disable caching for a page.  Caching can be disabled with a regular expression matching the specific page, or any other way.  If you served the two pages at different origins, the system could redirect.